# How does Java 8 lamada Stream: acquire the subset of attributes?

Tags: java, java-stream

Yes, there is an order list List that contains a number of goods in the order, and now wants to get the order list, all Id of goods, and the model structure is as follows:

```
class order{
int id,
List<goods> goodsList;
}

class goods{
int id;
String name;
}

List<order> list...
```

This gives you the Id list of orders, and the question now is how to get a list of collections of goods Id all list orders.

```
list.stream ().Map (c->c.getId ()).Collect (Collectors.toList ())
```

The following writing seems to be wrong

```
List.stream ().Map (c->c.getGoodsList ().Stream ().Map (q->q.getId ()).Collect (Collectors.toList ());
```

Comment: You want `List<goods>` as output?

Comment: Please take care of your capitals and the Java coding conventions. Methods in Java start with lowercase - there is no method `Map` on `Stream` - only `map`, `collect`, etc. For class names - they should start with capitals: `class Order`, `class Goods`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

```
final List<Good> goods = orders.stream().flatMap(o -> o.getGoodsList().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to get goodIds, it should be something like this,

```
final List<Integer> goodIds = orders.stream().flatMap(o -> o.getGoodsList().stream()).map(Good::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that there is a problem. I want to get a collection of goods ID.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> The question now is how to get a list of collections of goods under all list orders.

You can do it by `flatMap`:

```
List<order> list...
List<Integer> = list.stream()
                    .map(order::getGoodsList)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .map(goods::getId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want a set of unique goods ID, you can replace `toList` by `toSet`.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that there is a problem. I want to get a collection of goods ID.

Comment: Thank you very much